# retrieve "other message" on facebook with fql

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-fql

Can I retrieve https://www.facebook.com/messages/other/ messages with Facebook query?
Now I'm able to retrieve a normal message, from the thread table.

```
SELECT subject,snippet,snippet_author 
FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 AND unread != 0
```

But I need to retrieve "other" messages too...

Answer (score 0):

[Docs for the `thread` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/thread) say for folder_id: *“The ID can be one of: 0 (for Inbox), 1 (for Outbox), or 4 (for Updates).”*

[`unified_thread`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_thread) however has a `folder` field: *“Folder name ('inbox', 'other' or 'spam')”* – so there it seems you can chose `other`, so please give it a try and see if you can get what you’re after from this table (and the other unified_-tables if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

***For this all you need an app token :***

You first must get the *folder_id* where is the message: //0 inbox, 1 otubox, 4 updates//

```
SELECT folder_id, name, unread_count, viewer_id FROM mailbox_folder WHERE viewer_id=me()
```

When get the *folder_id* you can get the *thread_id* :

```
SELECT thread_id  FROM thread WHERE folder_id = x AND viewer_id=me()
```

And with this *thread_id* you get all the messages from it:

```
SELECT message_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id = xxxxxxx
```

and all summarized:

```
SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id   in (SELECT thread_id  FROM thread WHERE folder_id in(SELECT folder_id  FROM mailbox_folder WHERE viewer_id=me()) AND viewer_id=me())
```

you can try it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer